# DataTable not populating a datatype fully in sql server

Tags: c#, datatable, sql-server-2012, sql-types

I am having a very strange I am getting null values in a stored procedure that I've created.

I have created a type something like this:

```
CREATE TYPE [EAC].[PersonTableType] AS TABLE(
    [Title] [nvarchar](5) NULL,
    [FirstName] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [MiddleName] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [LastName] [nvarchar](25) NULL,
    [DisplayName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Suffix] [nvarchar](5) NULL,
    [WorkPhone] [nvarchar](25) NULL,
    [Extension] [nvarchar](8) NULL,
    [HomePhone] [nvarchar](25) NULL,
    [CellPhone] [nvarchar](25) NULL,
    [Pager] [nvarchar](25) NULL,
    [Fax] [nvarchar](25) NULL,
    [EMail] [nvarchar](75) NULL,
    [SecondaryEMail] [nvarchar](75) NULL,
    [Notes] [nvarchar](2000) NULL,
    [Department] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Position] [nvarchar](120) NULL,
    [Building] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Office] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [LicensePlateNumber] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [EmployeeId] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [Company] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [ExternalId] [nvarchar](400) NULL,
    [ZoneID] [int] NULL,
    [LastModifiedUTCOffset] [smallint] NULL
)
```

I want to say that the stored procedure works if I create a type and pass it in via SSMS. So I don't think that its the `PROC`.

I've also noticed that all of the fields are populated except for LastName.

```cs
foreach (var contract in people)
{
     var row = dataTable.NewRow();
     row["Title"] = contract. Title;
     row["FirstName"] = contract.FirstName ;
     row["MiddleName"] = contract.MiddleInitial ;
     row["LastName"] = contract.LastName ;
     row["DisplayName"] = contract.DisplayName ;
     row["Suffix"] = contract.Suffix ;
     row["WorkPhone"] = contract.WorkPhone ;
     row["Extension"] = contract.Extension ;
     row["HomePhone"] = contract.HomePhone ;
     row["CellPhone"] = contract.CellPhone ;
     row["Pager"] = contract.Pager ;
     row["Fax"] = contract.Fax ;
     row["EMail"] = contract.EmailAddress ;
     row["SecondaryEMail"] = contract.SecondaryEmailAddress ;
     row["Notes"] = contract.Notes ;
     row["Department"] = contract.Department ;
     row["Position"] = contract.Position ;
     row["Building"] = contract.Building ;
     row["Office"] = contract.Office ;
     row["LicensePlateNumber"] = contract.LicensePlateNumber ;
     row["EmployeeId"] = contract.EmployeeId ;
     row["Company"] = contract.Company ;
     row["ExternalId"] = contract.ExternalId ;
     row["ZoneID"] = contract.ZoneID ;
     row["LastModifiedUTCOffset"] = contract.LastModifiedUTCOffset ;


       dataTable.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

Comment: Well, now your code is fixed, so it doesn't have the out of order issue you mention in your answer. If you want the answer to be useful for future readers, I suggest just using an example where the table type has three columns and the code references those columns in a different order. Trying to line up 30 columns and spot the issue isn't a fun exercise for anyone.

Comment: the issue wasn't that it was being populated out of order, it was that the columns were added to the dataTable out of order.

Comment: I don't even use the word "populated" so I'm not sure what semantics you're talking about. *You* said "all of the fields are populated except for LastName" but your C# code was also missing three other columns, so my earlier question was asking how those columns could possibly have been populated.

Answer (score 0):

I actually have figured out the reason this happened. When you're passing in the data from the datatable the columns actually have to be in the same order as the type definition that you created.

Hope this helps others.